# Output returned data from mongo to jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, pug

I get something like this in the console.

```
[ { __v: 0,
city: 'on1',
address: '111',
first: 'user',
last: 'one',
chart: 'char1',
doctor: 'doc1',
_id: 5698a803d98f05482ba48a4b },
{ __v: 0,
city: 'city2',
address: 'address2',
first: 'first2',
last: 'last2',
chart: 'char2',
doctor: 'doc2',
_id: 5698d7c56d090e5c28b88f83 } ]
```

and I want to get all the values in a span tag like `<span> on1 </span>` and `<span> address </span>`.
I want to do something like this.

```
Patient.find({}, function(err, patients){
    console.log(patients)
    city = patients[0].city
    res.render("table.jade", {test : "test", patient : patients})
})
```

jade:

```
   each val, index in patients
        span= val
```

Also is it normal for me to get an array? I thought I would get an object

EDIT:
I tried this and it didn't work.

```
        - for (var g = 0; g < patients.length; g++){
        //- // - alert("hello")
           span= patients["city"]
       - }
```

Comment: Your mongo query returned multiple results. That is why it is in an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `g` in the `for` loop represents the index of a single patient. You should use this to access the patient:

```
for (var g = 0; g < patients.length; g++) {
    span= patients[g]['city']
}
```